# Redux-form redirect to unknown url

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create a form using [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) and use it in a project based on [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)

Here is my container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from '../modules/login'

import Login from '../components/Login'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loginUser,
  logoutUser,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

and here is the form

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Input, Button, Card, CardText, CardTitle } from 'react-toolbox';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const Login = props => (
  <form onSubmit={props.loginUser}>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <Field name="email" component="input" type="email"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <Field name="password" component="input" type="password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);

export default reduxForm({ form: 'login' })(Login);
```

The `loginUser` function looks like

```
export function loginUser(creds) {
  const config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: creds.email,
      password: creds.password,
    }),
  };

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds))

    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', config)
      .then(response => response.json().then(user => ({ user, response })))
      .then(({ user, response }) => {
        if (user.errors) {
          const errors = user.errors.map(error => error.detail);
          dispatch(loginError(errors))
          return Promise.reject(loginError(errors));
        }
        dispatch(receiveLogin(user));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));
  };
}
```

This function is called but I'm redirect to

```
http://localhost:3000/login?email=test%40test.com&password=test
```

and I cannot find why. Do you have any idea ?

---

Here are the actions

```
function requestLogin(creds) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    isFetching: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    creds,
  };
}

function receiveLogin(user) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    id_token: user.id_token,
  };
}

function loginError(message) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    message,
  };
}
```

Comment: Did you search in `loginError()` ? a redirect may be dispatched inside

Comment: Do you actually see POST request being made?

Comment: No POST request indeed. If I put `debugger` at the begining of the `loginUser` function, `creds` seems to be an event.

Comment: @DamienLeroux `loginError` is never reached

Comment: and in `requestLogin()`?

Comment: No. I added the actions in my posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your form onSubmit as-

```
 <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(props.loginUser)}>    
    </form>
```